# Can't find the error behind the undefined index

Tags: php

I have the following code, and i keep getting undefined index error, the code is failing on test5() but i'm unable to find the error.

```
<?php
function test1() {
$vars = [0, 1, 2, 4, 3];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($vars); $i++) {
    print $vars[$i] . "\n";
}
} 

function test2() {
$flavors = ['vanilla', 'pistachio', 'banana', 'caramel', 'strawberry'];
$favorite = 'banana';
foreach ($flavors as $key => $flavor) {
    if ($flavor === $favorite) {
        print $key . "\n";
        break;
    }
}
}

function test3() {
$stuff = ['shoes', 33, null, false, true];
$selected = 0;
foreach ($stuff as $key => $thing) {
    if ($thing == $selected) {
        print $key . "\n";
        break;
    }
}
}

function test4() {
$four = 4;
$five = test4_helper($four);
print "four: $four\n";
print "five: $five\n";
}

function test4_helper(&$arg) {
$return = $arg++;
return $return;
}

function test5() {

$products = [
    'Trek Fuel EX 8' => [
                                            'price' => 2000, 
                                            'quantity' => 1
                                            ],
    'Trek Remedy 9' => [
                                            'price' => 2600, 
                                            'quantity' => 2
                                             ],
    'Trek Scratch 8' => [
                                            'price' => 3500,    
                                            'quantity' => 1
                                            ]
];
$total = 0;

$callback = function ($product, $name) {
            //$total = 0;
            $tax = 1.2;
            $price = $product[$name]['price'];
            $total += ($price * $product[$name]['quantity']) * $tax;
           return $total;
        };

array_walk($products, $callback);

print "$total\n";
}

/* * **********************************

 * *** DO NOT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE ****

 * *********************************** */

$tests = 5;
for ($i = 1; $i <= $tests; $i++) {
$function = "test$i";
print "\n\n==== Test $i ====\n";
$function();
print "==== END of test $i ====\n <br>";
}
```

what is the problem with this code?
it looks that it's failing on test 5

Comment: Could you add the actual error message you're getting? It should tell you exactly which index is undefined.

Comment: array_walk passes each element of the array to the callback, not the whole array in one go

Comment: Is it real code or sample ? if it is , there are many mistake ?

Comment: Shouldn't those `[ ]` brackets in the array `products = [` `]` be `(` - `)` ? I've seen that happen before.

Comment: Or... missing closing brace `}` under or near `];` for the function.

Comment: @Fred - PHP >= 5.4.0 for short array syntax

Comment: I could be wrong but I believe that you should be using the `array()` syntax. I added your code to a [phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/) to confirm this and it ended up throwing an error...

Comment: I think this is more clear: "for ($i = 1; $i == $tests; $i++)". You don't want to stop your loop when the index is less that 5 right?

Comment: i'm getting this error [link](http://paste.laravel.com/W3d)

Comment: @MarkBaker Thank you Mark, I will read up on it. Thing is, the OP's problem had similarities I have noticed before, and thought that would be the same issue. *"I Live & Learn, just like Ansel Adams did."*

Comment: @AdibHanna If the error saying that `total` is an undefined variable, maybe it has to do with the placement of `$total = 0;` and/or naming it as `$total = "";` what if you were to place it at the top of your entire code, that way it should already be a defined variable.

Comment: @Fred i tired to move the variable to the top, nothing changed. still getting the same error

Comment: @AdibHanna  Why is there a semi-colon after your closing brace for `$callback = function ($product, $name) {` right after `return $total;`? That doesn't seem right, to me anyway. Unless someone else has other ideas. I'm out of options/ideas now.

Comment: @Fred-ii- because omitting the semi-colon would result in a syntax error

Comment: i fixed it, i needed to pass total by reference and use "use(&$total)"

Comment: in test 3 there seem to be a logical error, since it should return 2 and 3 bcz null and false are the same as 0. let me know if you can spot the error.

Answer (score 0):

PHP closures are not like JavaScript ones in that they do not inherit the parent scope. You need to pass in any dependencies via the `use` construct. In your example...

```
$callback = function ($product, $name) use ($total) {
    // etc
```

See http://php.net/manual/functions.anonymous.php#example-166

Comment: this is correct, but i also needed to pass total by reference so that i can print the total answer later on

Answer (score -1):

Arrays in PHP are defined like this:

```
$products = array(
    'Trek Fuel EX 8' => array(
                          'price' => 2000, 
                          'quantity' => 1
                          ),
    'Trek Remedy 9' => array(
                         'price' => 2600, 
                         'quantity' => 2
                         ),
    'Trek Scratch 8' => array(
                         'price' => 3500,    
                         'quantity' => 1
                         )
);
```

Which means you also need to look at `$vars = [0, 1, 2, 4, 3];` and `$flavors = ['vanilla', 'pistachio', 'banana', 'caramel', 'strawberry'];` and fix them too.

Comment: PHP 5.5 added the short array notation as $vars = [1, 2, 3, 4];

Comment: @francisco.preller So it did, I completely forgot. An ugly format but you are correct, my mistake.